# AWS Lambda trying to access AWS Parameter Store using Java

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-parameter-store

I have a AWS Lambda which is not associated to any VPC. It is trying to connect to AWS Parameter Store using Java. I have added GetParameter, GetParameters and GetParametersByPath permissions to it for the parameter store.

But I continue to get CONNECTION TIMEOUT WITH the following error

```
{
  **"errorMessage": "Failed to connect to service endpoint: "**,
  "errorType": "com.amazonaws.SdkClientException",
  "stackTrace": [
    "com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:100)",
    "com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:70)",
    "com.amazonaws.internal.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.readResource(InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.java:75)",
    "com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.readR
.
.
.
],
  "cause": {
    **"errorMessage": "connect timed out"**,
   ** "errorType": "java.net.SocketTimeoutException",**
    "stackTrace": [
      "java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)",
      "java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSo
```

ANY HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED :)

Comment: Can you show the code that is generating the error? It might be that a region is incorrectly defined.

Comment: I got it to work by removing withCredentials() method while creating the AWSSimpleSystemsManagement. Thanks!